# Derivative of one function with respect to another

Tags: calculus, derivatives

What is the derivative of $\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}-1}{x}\right)$ w.r.t. $\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2x\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1-2x^2}\right)$ at $x=0$? 
Take $l=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}-1}{x}\right)$ and $m=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2x\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1-2x^2}\right)$ and take $\frac{dl}{dx}$, $\frac{dm}{dx}$ and finally find $\frac{dl}{dm}$. But it takes long process. Is/Are there any shortcut method/methods?

Comment: Consider the functions as parametric with a parameter $x$. If you have two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, $\frac{df}{dg} = \frac{\frac{df}{dx}}{\frac{dg}{dx}}$

Comment: Thank you sir. I know that process. But is too long process.

Comment: That's the only way to do it in general

Comment: No sir there might be another method

Comment: @saisaandeep I'm not sure why you would expect a shortcut for this. There isn't always a quick-and-easy way to do everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $v=2\sin^{-1}(x)$. Note that $\sin(v/2)=x$ and $\cos(v/2)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$. Then 
$$
m = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2\sin(v/2)\cos(v/2)}{1-2\sin^2(v/2)}\right) = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sin(v)}{\cos(v)}\right) = \tan^{-1}\left(\tan(v)\right) = v = 2\sin^{-1}(x),
$$
or equivalently, 
$$
x = \sin(m/2).
$$

On the other hand, we have $l = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}-1}{x}\right)$, which implies
$$
\tan(l) = \frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}-1}{x} = \frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}+1}.
$$
Thus, we have
$$
\tan(2l) = \frac{2\tan(l)}{1-\tan^2(l)} = \frac{2\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}+1}}{1-\frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}-1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}+1}} = x.
$$
We have proven that $\tan(2l) = \sin(m/2)$, or equivalently $l = \frac{1}{2}\tan^{-1}(\sin(m/2))$. Then we obtain $$
\frac{dl}{dm} = \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{1 + \sin^2(m/2)} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cos(m/2) = \frac{1}{4}\frac{\cos(m/2)}{1 + \sin^2(m/2)}.
$$

Substituting $\sin(m/2) = x$ and $\cos(m/2) = \sqrt{1-x^2}$ in the above equation, we obtain
$$
\frac{dl}{dm}@(x=0) = \frac{1}{4}\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1 + x^2}@(x=0) = \frac{1}{4}.
$$

Answer (score -1):

Let $\arctan x=2y\implies\tan2y=x$ and $-\dfrac\pi2\le2y\le\dfrac\pi2$

$\implies\sqrt{1+x^2}=|\sec2y|=+\sec2y$

$$\dfrac{\sqrt{1+x^2}-1}x=\dfrac{\sec2y-1}{\tan2y}=\tan y$$

$$\implies u=\arctan\dfrac{\sqrt{1+x^2}-1}x=y=\dfrac{\arctan x}2$$

$\dfrac{du}{dx}=\dfrac1{2(1+x^2)}$

For $\dfrac{2x\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1-2x^2},$  let $\arcsin x=z\implies x=\sin z$

$\sqrt{1-x^2}=|\cos z|=+\cos z$

$\dfrac{2x\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1-2x^2}=\cdots=\tan2z$

$v=\arctan\dfrac{2x\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1-2x^2}=\begin{cases} 2z &\mbox{if } -\dfrac\pi2\le2z\le\dfrac\pi2 \\
\pi+2z & \mbox{if } 2z\le-\dfrac\pi2\\
2z-\pi  & \mbox{if } 2z\ge\dfrac\pi2
 \end{cases} $

$\dfrac{dv}{dx}=\dfrac2{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: The OP was asking for a shortcut... Not to mention that I do not see the derivatives.

Comment: @AlexM., Please find the updated answer. Please let me know your confusion/queries OR you have found one shortcut solution